# Why can't I pass in a parameter to function in a for loop

Tags: javascript

Trying to pass `i` into the closure to make it local to avoid the closure issue of `i` remaining at 2.

```
var myFunctions = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions

    myFunctions[i] = function(i) {  // and store them in myFunctions
        console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
    };

}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    myFunctions[j]();              // and now let's run each one to see
}

// > "My value: undefined
// > "My value: undefined
// > "My value: undefined
```

Comment: Well when you call the functions, you're **not** passing a parameter.

Comment: I'm an idiot :)

Comment: invoke it like `myFunctions[j](j);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that's happening is because you've got `i` as a parameter of the functions, but then you don't pass a value.

There are three ways to fix this.

---

First, you can pass the value as a function parameter:

```
myFunctions[j](j);
```

---

The second way would be to use a function closure to store the value:

```
var myFunctions = {}

function generateValuePrintout (value) {
    return function () {
        console.log("My value: " + value);
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    myFunctions[i] = generateValuePrintout(i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    myFunctions[j]();
}
```

This is a cleaner way to do it than the first because it means you don't need to pass any value into the function for it to know about its closure.

---

The last way (my favourite) would be to store the value for the function using `let` (so that it is scoped correctly), and then call it without a parameter (remove the parameter from the function definition also):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions

    let closureValue = i;

    myFunctions[i] = function() {  // and store them in myFunctions
        console.log("My value: " + closureValue); // each should log its value.
    };

}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    myFunctions[j]();              // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

The output of each will be:

> My value: 0
>
> My value: 1
>
> My value: 2

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `i` in the function definition is what is expected as a parameter to the function

try this

```
var myFunctions = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions

    myFunctions[i] = function(i) {  // and store them in myFunctions
        console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
    };

}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    myFunctions[j](j);              // pass j as parameter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function without passing the parameter it requires.

```
var myFunctions = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    myFunctions[i] = function (i) {
        console.log("My value: " + i);
    };
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    myFunctions[j](j); // Passing the required parameter
}

// > "My value: 0
// > "My value: 1
// > "My value: 2
```

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was clear enough. I have attached the fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

though parameter is not necessarry in javascript

but if you want value to be used which is in parameter that should be there

```
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
myFunctions[j]("name"+j);              // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

output

```
My value: name0

My value: name1

My value: name2
```